# CASE INNER JOIN в MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Есть задача заменить содержимое `user_id` содержимым `to_user_id` при условии, что `type = 'report'` и дальше найти содержимое в таблицу `tbl_users` по `user_id`
Рабочий запрос, но при вызове данных из `tbl_users` не учитываются замены в `user_id`:

```
SELECT tbl_application_reports.user_id, 
tbl_application_reports.to_user_id, 
tbl_application_reports.type, 
CASE WHEN tbl_application_reports.type = 'report' THEN tbl_application_reports.to_user_id ELSE tbl_application_reports.user_id END as user_id 
FROM tbl_application_reports 
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_application_reports.user_id = tbl_users.user_id 
WHERE app_id = 123;
```